# Accessing Master page LinkButton.Text property from content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I think the issue is something obvious that I'm missing but I cannot figure it out even after googling quite extensively. I am working on an eCommerce site and I have a cart link on the master page that I would like to update with the number of items in the cart. Currently, I store that number in cookies. Anyways, I have an 'Add to cart' method that adds all the appropriate cart items to the cookie but the Master page loads before the method runs. SO I would like to set the LinkButton.Text from the content page but I haven't been successful. I have tried using get; set; on a public property in the master page as well as using

```
    ((LinkButton)this.Master.FindControl("linkButton")).Text = string.Format("Your Cart Contains {0} Item(s)", cookie.Values["itemsincart"]);
```

When I step through the code it changes it but then it changes back. This leads me to believe that I'm accessing the wrong master page but I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried strongly typing the MasterPage and accessing the property directly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228274(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out that I was making a pretty common mistake, I needed to wrap my LinkButton in an update panel and then put the update method in the Page_PreRender() event because in the AJAX/ASPX life cycle the Page_Load event occurs before the button method fires.